# Is it possible to play Minecraft without migrating my Mojang account to a Microsoft account?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I do not want to migrate my accounts for various personal reasons, like Microsoft's "secure chat" update and a lot of others.

However, they won't let me play the game otherwise. They keep telling me to migrate my account and won't let me play.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In order to continue playing, the account migration process that was rolled out starting in March of 2022 must be performed according to [their FAQs](https://help.minecraft.net/hc/en-us/articles/360050865492-Minecraft-Java-Edition-Account-Migration-FAQ#h_01GCSRFBRBADJDK8HMG9K3YMS9):

> ##### Do I have to migrate my Mojang account to a Microsoft account?
>
> If you use a Mojang account, you will need to migrate to a Microsoft account to continue playing Minecraft: Java Edition. Your account/profile will remain, but **you will not be able to access the game until you complete migration**. **Migration is mandatory**, but it won't be for everyone all at once; it will roll out to players in waves, which will begin on March 10, 2022.

It also states:

> ##### What if I don't want to migrate my Mojang account to a Microsoft account? What happens if my migration period starts and I'm not ready to change yet?
>
> You'll have time to migrate—you don't have to move right when you get the notification. However, when the voluntary migration period ends, you'll need to move your account or **risk not being able to play the game.**

Thus, if you don't migrate, you can't play the game legitimately.

Comment: Presumably it would be "legitimate" to never run the game connected to the internet again after the migration period, since Minecraft will AFAIK let you play without an internet connection.

Comment: @pppery I would assume. I meant more so "officially" instead of "other means"...